# Form: how to display value as text under div on Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#value").change(function() {
var src = $(this).val();
$("#valuePreview").html($(this).val());
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="value" id="value" class="inputbox" size="1">
<option value=""> - Select Value- </option>
<option value="red">lamp1</option>
<option value="orange">lamp2</option>
<option value="green">lamp3</option>
</select>
<div id="valuePreview">displays value here</div>
```

How to display value (red, orange, green) in div?

Comment: It's working fine. [See a live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/juFTu/1/)

Comment: Um...can you confirm the problem as your code seems to work as expected. See http://jsfiddle.net/876nM/ EDIT: Or what everyone else says.

Comment: -1 because code works fine never tested before posting

Comment: That's strange because it doesn't work for me but I can make it work with kasdega script. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works the only thing I'd change is to use the variable you set "src" or don't set it...

[Working JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net./JXMHJ/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#value").change(function() {
      var src = $(this).val();
      $("#valuePreview").html(src);
   });
});
```